# Symfony2: Persisting user entry to the database

Tags: database, forms, symfony, submit

I have got a form in Symfony2 that is displayed onto a Twig Template. I wanted to know what is the business logic of the Controller that would save the users entries into the database? I have attempted the code below but it is not inserting into the database. Many thanks:)

```html
 /**
     * @Route("/lot", name="sort")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function bestAction(Request $request)
    {
            $quest = new quest();
            $form = $this->createForm(new QuestType(), $quest, array(
//                'action' => $this->generateUrl('best'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($entity->isValid()){

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('IWABundle:quest');

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('IWABundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

```html
{% block form %}
                  {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('sort'), 'method':'POST'}) }}
                  {{ form_start(form.email) }}
                  {{ form_start(form.firstname) }}
                  {{ form_start(form.enqiry) }}
                  {{ form_end(form) }}
          {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are filling in the details for the `$quest` object when you use the form but then after that you are getting a repository and then trying to persist that to the database. If you remove the `$entity = $em->getRepository('IWABundle:quest');` and instead persist the `$quest` object  to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the entity (`$quest`) with the entity manager:

```
/**
 * @Route("/lot", name="sort")
 * @Template()
 */
public function bestAction(Request $request)
{
    // 1) Create your empty entity
    $quest = new Quest();

    // 2) Create your form from its type and empty entity
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestType(), $quest, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    // 3) Handle the request
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // 4) Check if the form is valid
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // 5) Get the entity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        // 6) Persist the new entity and flush the changes to the database
        $em->persist($quest);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('IWABundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Check out the official documentation on [how to persist objects to the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) and [how to manage form submission](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions).